# Remove string from one character to another c#

Tags: c#

I have the following string:

```
"Downloads-Size:2090493403 bytes, Number of files: 39\Folder1-Size:748334 bytes, Number of files: 3\someFile.exe-Size: 545454 bytes"
```

What i need is to delete from `"-Size: ... till \"` so that the string should look like `Downloads\Folder1\someFile.exe`

I appreciate all help.

Here is what i did so far

```
    private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {

        folderPath = e.Node.FullPath;

        String treeNode = treeView1.SelectedNode.ToString().Replace("TreeNode: ", String.Empty);

        String treeNodeName = treeNode.Substring(0, treeNode.LastIndexOf('-'));

        MessageBox.Show(folderPath);
      }
```

Comment: there are a lot of ways you can do that; regex or indexof would be the first two things to look at - have you tried those? how did it go?

Comment: As @MarcGravell suggests, there are many ways, you could use the slash as a split char "\" along with "-Size"

Comment: i tried with indexof but could not write the code correctly. I am getting that string from treeview.  folderPath = e.Node.FullPath; so i get that path from fullpath property.

Comment: "i tried with indexof but could not write the code correctly." - I'll be frank: Stack Overflow is a lot more receptive if you post an *attempt* at code that isn't working correctly, so we can help you with that - if you'd posted the attempt, we'd be *all over that*; "write this for me" doesn't tend to go down well

Comment: ok. i will try with split function.

Comment: sorry. I will post my code now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `String.Split` and `String.Join`.

```
var text = @"Downloads-Size:2090493403 bytes, Number of files: 39\Folder1-Size:748334 bytes, Number of files: 3\someFile.exe-Size: 545454 bytes";
var splits = text.Split(new string[] {"-Size", "\\"}, StringSplitOptions.None);  
var output  =  string.Join("\\", splits.Where((x, i) => i % 2 == 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the split function like this

```
        string str = @"Downloads-Size:2090493403 bytes, Number of files: 39\Folder1-Size:748334 bytes, Number of files: 3\someFile.exe-Size: 545454 bytes";
        string[] strs = str.Split(',');

        string result = strs[0].Split('-')[0]
            + "\\" + strs[1].Split('\\')[1].Split('-')[0]
            + "\\" +  strs[2].Split('\\')[1].Split('-')[0];
```

You will need some error checking in production code, in case the string is not always in the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

```
string text = @"Downloads-Size:2090493403 bytes, Number of files: 39\Folder1-Size:748334 bytes, Number of files: 3\someFile.exe-Size: 545454 bytes";
while (text.Contains("-Size")) {
    int start = text.IndexOf("-Size");
    int end = text.IndexOf(@"\", start);
    int length = end < 0 ? text.Length - start : end - start;
    string remove = text.Substring(start, length);
    text = text.Replace(remove, string.Empty);
}
```